# Blinking effect for logo icon in Android 12 Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-animation, android-12, android-splashscreen

Whenever my app is launched then a color chaning animation is supposed to be played and after that the Splash Screen also needs to be removed from the screen via a translation animation, but just before the translation animation of the Splash Screen the logo blinks as it can be seen in the gif

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="prateek_gupta.physical_device_tester">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**splash_screen.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#ff9900</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_logo_animation</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">2000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.PhysicalDeviceTester</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**splash_screen_logo_animation.xml**

```xml
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="322dp"
            android:height="156dp"
            android:viewportWidth="322"
            android:viewportHeight="156">
            <group
                android:name="group"
                android:pivotX="161"
                android:pivotY="78"
                android:scaleX="0.8"
                android:scaleY="0.4">
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    android:pathData="M 166 35 C 166 62.8 166.2 67 167.5 67 C 168.8 67 169 62.8 169 35 C 169 7.2 168.8 3 167.5 3 C 166.2 3 166 7.2 166 35 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:pathData="M 221.2 22.6 C 218.7 27.6 217.7 32 219 32 C 220.6 32 225.4 21 224.2 19.8 C 223.5 19.1 222.6 20 221.2 22.6 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    android:pathData="M 113 22 C 113 25.1 116.8 32 118.5 32 C 119.8 32 119.9 31.6 118.6 28.7 C 114.7 19.8 113 17.8 113 22 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_3"
                    android:pathData="M 195.7 22.1 C 195 24.6 191 40.3 188.4 51 C 186.9 56.8 184.6 65.9 183.2 71.2 C 180.4 81.9 180.7 81.7 172.8 80.4 C 169.4 79.8 169.1 79.4 168.8 76.2 C 168.4 71 166 70.8 166 75.9 C 166 79.2 165.7 80 164.1 80 C 163.1 80 160.9 80.3 159.2 80.6 C 156.3 81.2 156.2 81.1 154.6 75.7 C 153.7 72.7 153 69.4 153 68.3 C 153 67.3 151.3 60 149.1 52 C 147 44 144.4 34 143.5 29.7 C 142.4 24.5 141.4 22 140.4 22 C 138.4 22 138.6 22.9 142.5 36.9 C 144.4 43.8 146 50.3 146 51.4 C 146.1 52.6 147.8 59.6 149.9 67 L 153.8 80.5 L 151 81.7 C 149.5 82.4 147.2 83.2 145.9 83.5 C 143.3 84.2 142.8 83.3 131.8 58.5 C 123.8 40.7 122 37 121 37 C 119.2 37 119.9 39.3 124.6 49.5 C 128.7 58.4 131.8 65.4 138.8 81.2 C 141.1 86.3 141 86.5 135.4 89.3 C 132.4 90.8 132.2 90.8 130.1 88.6 C 129 87.4 128 86 128 85.4 C 128 84.9 126.8 83.1 125.4 81.5 C 122.8 78.5 114.5 66.6 112.4 62.9 C 111.8 61.8 110.4 59.9 109.3 58.7 C 108.3 57.5 105.7 53.9 103.6 50.7 C 99.9 45.2 99 44.4 97.7 45.6 C 97.2 46.1 99.4 49.6 108.5 62.2 C 110.2 64.4 112.1 67.5 112.9 68.9 C 113.7 70.3 114.9 71.9 115.5 72.5 C 116.7 73.5 126.2 87 128.8 91.4 C 129.9 93.3 129.7 93.8 127 96.2 C 125.3 97.8 123.6 99 123.1 99 C 122.7 99 120.6 97.3 118.4 95.2 C 116.3 93.2 110.7 88.1 106.1 84 C 95.3 74.3 94 73.1 89.9 69.5 C 88 67.8 82 62.4 76.5 57.5 C 62.9 45.4 63.3 45.7 62.6 46.9 C 62.2 47.4 70.4 55.4 80.7 64.6 C 102.3 83.8 105.7 86.9 111.5 92.7 C 113.8 95.1 116.2 97 116.7 97 C 118.2 97 121 100.4 121 102.3 C 121 104.1 116.9 110.9 115.7 111 C 115.2 111 113.4 109.9 111.7 108.6 C 109.9 107.3 107.5 105.9 106.3 105.5 C 105 105.2 104 104.4 104 103.9 C 104 103.4 103.3 103 102.5 103 C 99.6 103 101.1 104.8 107.5 109.1 C 113.7 113.4 113.9 113.6 113.3 117 C 112.4 122.6 111.7 122.7 103.2 119.6 C 99 118.1 93.3 116.1 90.5 115.3 C 87.8 114.4 80.6 112.1 74.5 110 C 48.2 101.1 48 101 48 103.5 C 48 104.4 48.9 105 50.3 105 C 51.5 105 57.2 106.8 63 109 C 68.8 111.2 74.1 113 74.8 113 C 75.6 113 81.2 114.7 87.3 116.9 C 93.5 119 101.2 121.6 104.5 122.7 L 110.5 124.7 L 110.2 130.5 C 110.1 133.8 109.8 136.6 109.5 136.8 C 109.3 137 104 136.5 97.8 135.7 C 91.6 134.9 86.2 134.4 85.8 134.7 C 84.2 135.6 86.2 137 89.2 137 C 90.9 137 96.3 137.5 101.1 138.2 L 110 139.4 L 110 145.7 L 110 152 L 69.1 152 C 42.8 152 27.9 152.4 27.5 153 C 27.1 153.7 72.8 154 164 154 C 255.2 154 300.9 153.7 300.5 153 C 300.1 152.4 286.2 152 261.9 152 L 224 152 L 224 145.5 C 224 141.9 224.3 139.1 224.8 139.2 C 225.2 139.3 231.2 138.8 238.3 138 C 247.7 137 251 136.3 251 135.3 C 251 134.3 250.1 134.1 247.8 134.5 C 235.5 136.6 224.8 137.6 224.5 136.6 C 224.3 136 223.9 133.2 223.7 130.5 L 223.2 125.5 L 230.8 123.1 C 235 121.8 243.5 119 249.6 116.9 C 255.7 114.7 261.3 113 262.1 113 C 262.9 113 268.2 111.2 274 109 C 279.8 106.8 285.5 105 286.7 105 C 289.2 105 290.6 103.5 288.9 102.4 C 287.8 101.7 280.1 103.9 264 109.7 C 258.8 111.5 252.3 113.6 249.5 114.4 C 246.8 115.1 240.7 117.1 236 118.7 C 222.2 123.6 222.5 123.6 221.2 119.1 C 219.7 114.3 219.7 114 221.3 114 C 223.2 114 236.1 105 235.5 104.1 C 234.9 103.1 230.3 105.3 223.8 109.8 C 218.5 113.5 218 113.6 218 111.4 C 218 110.5 217 108.4 215.8 106.8 L 213.7 103.7 L 220.8 97.1 C 224.8 93.5 230.5 88.2 233.6 85.5 C 248.1 72.7 249.7 71 246.9 71 C 245.9 71 235.4 79.9 226.9 88 C 222.8 91.8 216.3 97.7 214.3 99.4 C 212.1 101.3 212 101.2 208.9 98.2 L 205.8 95.2 L 210.4 88.2 C 213 84.4 215.7 80.7 216.5 80 C 217.3 79.3 218 78.3 218 77.8 C 218 76.9 221.8 71.5 230.6 59.5 C 232.4 57.2 234.3 54.2 235 52.9 C 235.7 51.6 237.1 49.5 238.2 48.4 C 239.7 46.7 239.8 46 238.9 45.4 C 238.1 45 237.1 45.4 236.3 46.6 C 235.5 47.6 233.5 50.5 231.7 52.9 C 229.9 55.3 227.9 58.5 227.1 59.9 C 226.3 61.3 224.2 64.3 222.3 66.4 C 220.5 68.6 219 70.9 219 71.6 C 219 72.3 218.7 73 218.3 73.2 C 217.1 73.7 211 81.7 211 82.7 C 211 83.2 209.2 85.7 207.1 88.2 C 203.7 92.4 203.1 92.8 201.9 91.4 C 201.2 90.5 199.6 89.4 198.3 88.9 C 195.5 87.9 195.4 85.5 197.8 81.5 C 198.8 79.8 200.6 76 201.7 73 C 202.9 70 205.2 64.7 206.9 61.3 C 208.6 57.9 210 54.8 210 54.4 C 210 54 211.6 50.4 213.5 46.4 C 217.1 38.9 217.6 37 216.1 37 C 214.9 37 212.2 41.2 211.4 44.5 C 211 46 209 50.7 207 54.9 C 204.9 59.1 202.9 63.6 202.5 65 C 202.1 66.3 200.2 70.4 198.4 74 C 196.6 77.6 194.8 81.8 194.5 83.3 C 194.1 84.8 193.7 86 193.5 86 C 193.4 86 191.2 85.1 188.6 84 L 184 81.9 L 184.6 77.7 C 184.9 75.4 187.1 66.1 189.5 57 C 197 28 198.2 22.8 197.1 21.7 C 196.4 21 195.9 21.1 195.7 22.1 Z M 179 83.9 C 195.5 88.8 204.3 94.9 212.6 107.2 C 218.8 116.5 220.1 121.6 220.7 138.3 L 221.2 152 L 166.5 152 L 111.7 152 L 112.2 139.8 C 112.8 127.1 113.9 122.6 118.8 112 C 121.3 106.5 124.9 102 130.4 97.1 C 132 95.7 134.7 93.2 136.4 91.7 C 138.1 90.2 140.6 88.6 142 88.3 C 143.4 87.9 146.4 86.8 148.8 85.8 C 157.9 81.7 169.3 81 179 83.9 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_4"
                    android:pathData="M 50 36.3 C 50 37.5 58.2 45 59.4 45 C 61 45 59.5 42.4 55.9 38.9 C 51.7 34.8 50 34.1 50 36.3 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_5"
                    android:pathData="M 267 51.8 C 265.6 53.3 261.7 57 258.2 60 C 252 65.5 250.9 67 253.3 67 C 255.1 67 272.3 50.6 271.4 49.7 C 270.3 48.6 269.7 48.9 267 51.8 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_6"
                    android:pathData="M 74 87 C 74 87.5 74.4 88 74.9 88 C 75.4 88 77.1 89.1 78.7 90.4 C 84 94.9 97.9 102.9 98.6 101.9 C 98.9 101.3 99 100.7 98.9 100.6 C 98.7 100.4 95.8 98.5 92.6 96.4 C 77 86.1 74 84.6 74 87 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_7"
                    android:pathData="M 256.9 88.4 C 255 89.5 250.7 92.3 247.3 94.5 C 244 96.7 240.4 99 239.4 99.6 C 238 100.5 237.8 101.1 238.6 101.9 C 239.3 102.7 240.6 102.3 243.1 100.4 C 244.9 99 247.4 97.4 248.5 96.9 C 252.2 95.3 262.9 87.2 262.3 86.6 C 261.4 85.8 261 85.9 256.9 88.4 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_8"
                    android:pathData="M 3.5 124.9 C 2.7 126.3 6.1 127.6 13.3 128.4 C 17.9 128.9 19 128.7 19 127.6 C 19 126.6 17.4 125.9 14.3 125.5 C 11.6 125.2 8.3 124.6 6.8 124.4 C 5.4 124.1 3.9 124.4 3.5 124.9 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_9"
                    android:pathData="M 299.5 128.2 C 290.7 129.2 277.3 130.8 269.7 131.7 C 256.6 133.3 254.2 133.9 255.4 135.8 C 255.7 136.3 266.6 135.1 279.7 133.3 C 292.8 131.5 307.2 129.6 311.8 129.2 C 316.3 128.8 320.1 128 320.1 127.5 C 320.1 126 316.9 126.1 299.5 128.2 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_10"
                    android:pathData="M 23 127.7 C 23 128.2 35.3 130.3 50.3 132.4 C 84.2 137 81.5 136.8 81.5 135 C 81.5 133.5 71.7 131.9 43.5 129 C 37.5 128.4 30.4 127.6 27.8 127.3 C 25 127 23 127.1 23 127.7 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_3">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_4">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_5">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_6">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_7">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_8">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_9">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_10">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#cc0000"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package prateek_gupta.physical_device_tester;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreenViewProvider;

import prateek_gupta.physical_device_tester.databinding.ActivityMain2Binding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMain2Binding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener(new SplashScreen.OnExitAnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSplashScreenExit(@NonNull SplashScreenViewProvider splashScreenViewProvider) {
                TranslateAnimation rightTranslateAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,-1f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0f);
                splashScreenViewProvider.getIconAnimationDurationMillis();
                rightTranslateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                //rightTranslateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                rightTranslateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        splashScreenViewProvider.remove();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                splashScreenViewProvider.getView().startAnimation(rightTranslateAnimation);


            }
        });
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
}}
```

So my question is how can I avoid the blinking of the logo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the blinking effect is refreshing of Splash Screen View when the animation for the logo gets over and the exit animation of the Splash Screen starts.

So to avoid this blinking effect, change the logo animation so that the logo merges with the background (or we can say the logo fades out).

Updated **splash_screen_logo_animation.xml**

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="322dp"
            android:height="156dp"
            android:viewportWidth="322"
            android:viewportHeight="156">
            <group
                android:name="group"
                android:pivotX="161"
                android:pivotY="78"
                android:scaleX="0.8"
                android:scaleY="0.4">
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    android:pathData="M 166 35 C 166 62.8 166.2 67 167.5 67 C 168.8 67 169 62.8 169 35 C 169 7.2 168.8 3 167.5 3 C 166.2 3 166 7.2 166 35 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:pathData="M 221.2 22.6 C 218.7 27.6 217.7 32 219 32 C 220.6 32 225.4 21 224.2 19.8 C 223.5 19.1 222.6 20 221.2 22.6 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    android:pathData="M 113 22 C 113 25.1 116.8 32 118.5 32 C 119.8 32 119.9 31.6 118.6 28.7 C 114.7 19.8 113 17.8 113 22 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_3"
                    android:pathData="M 195.7 22.1 C 195 24.6 191 40.3 188.4 51 C 186.9 56.8 184.6 65.9 183.2 71.2 C 180.4 81.9 180.7 81.7 172.8 80.4 C 169.4 79.8 169.1 79.4 168.8 76.2 C 168.4 71 166 70.8 166 75.9 C 166 79.2 165.7 80 164.1 80 C 163.1 80 160.9 80.3 159.2 80.6 C 156.3 81.2 156.2 81.1 154.6 75.7 C 153.7 72.7 153 69.4 153 68.3 C 153 67.3 151.3 60 149.1 52 C 147 44 144.4 34 143.5 29.7 C 142.4 24.5 141.4 22 140.4 22 C 138.4 22 138.6 22.9 142.5 36.9 C 144.4 43.8 146 50.3 146 51.4 C 146.1 52.6 147.8 59.6 149.9 67 L 153.8 80.5 L 151 81.7 C 149.5 82.4 147.2 83.2 145.9 83.5 C 143.3 84.2 142.8 83.3 131.8 58.5 C 123.8 40.7 122 37 121 37 C 119.2 37 119.9 39.3 124.6 49.5 C 128.7 58.4 131.8 65.4 138.8 81.2 C 141.1 86.3 141 86.5 135.4 89.3 C 132.4 90.8 132.2 90.8 130.1 88.6 C 129 87.4 128 86 128 85.4 C 128 84.9 126.8 83.1 125.4 81.5 C 122.8 78.5 114.5 66.6 112.4 62.9 C 111.8 61.8 110.4 59.9 109.3 58.7 C 108.3 57.5 105.7 53.9 103.6 50.7 C 99.9 45.2 99 44.4 97.7 45.6 C 97.2 46.1 99.4 49.6 108.5 62.2 C 110.2 64.4 112.1 67.5 112.9 68.9 C 113.7 70.3 114.9 71.9 115.5 72.5 C 116.7 73.5 126.2 87 128.8 91.4 C 129.9 93.3 129.7 93.8 127 96.2 C 125.3 97.8 123.6 99 123.1 99 C 122.7 99 120.6 97.3 118.4 95.2 C 116.3 93.2 110.7 88.1 106.1 84 C 95.3 74.3 94 73.1 89.9 69.5 C 88 67.8 82 62.4 76.5 57.5 C 62.9 45.4 63.3 45.7 62.6 46.9 C 62.2 47.4 70.4 55.4 80.7 64.6 C 102.3 83.8 105.7 86.9 111.5 92.7 C 113.8 95.1 116.2 97 116.7 97 C 118.2 97 121 100.4 121 102.3 C 121 104.1 116.9 110.9 115.7 111 C 115.2 111 113.4 109.9 111.7 108.6 C 109.9 107.3 107.5 105.9 106.3 105.5 C 105 105.2 104 104.4 104 103.9 C 104 103.4 103.3 103 102.5 103 C 99.6 103 101.1 104.8 107.5 109.1 C 113.7 113.4 113.9 113.6 113.3 117 C 112.4 122.6 111.7 122.7 103.2 119.6 C 99 118.1 93.3 116.1 90.5 115.3 C 87.8 114.4 80.6 112.1 74.5 110 C 48.2 101.1 48 101 48 103.5 C 48 104.4 48.9 105 50.3 105 C 51.5 105 57.2 106.8 63 109 C 68.8 111.2 74.1 113 74.8 113 C 75.6 113 81.2 114.7 87.3 116.9 C 93.5 119 101.2 121.6 104.5 122.7 L 110.5 124.7 L 110.2 130.5 C 110.1 133.8 109.8 136.6 109.5 136.8 C 109.3 137 104 136.5 97.8 135.7 C 91.6 134.9 86.2 134.4 85.8 134.7 C 84.2 135.6 86.2 137 89.2 137 C 90.9 137 96.3 137.5 101.1 138.2 L 110 139.4 L 110 145.7 L 110 152 L 69.1 152 C 42.8 152 27.9 152.4 27.5 153 C 27.1 153.7 72.8 154 164 154 C 255.2 154 300.9 153.7 300.5 153 C 300.1 152.4 286.2 152 261.9 152 L 224 152 L 224 145.5 C 224 141.9 224.3 139.1 224.8 139.2 C 225.2 139.3 231.2 138.8 238.3 138 C 247.7 137 251 136.3 251 135.3 C 251 134.3 250.1 134.1 247.8 134.5 C 235.5 136.6 224.8 137.6 224.5 136.6 C 224.3 136 223.9 133.2 223.7 130.5 L 223.2 125.5 L 230.8 123.1 C 235 121.8 243.5 119 249.6 116.9 C 255.7 114.7 261.3 113 262.1 113 C 262.9 113 268.2 111.2 274 109 C 279.8 106.8 285.5 105 286.7 105 C 289.2 105 290.6 103.5 288.9 102.4 C 287.8 101.7 280.1 103.9 264 109.7 C 258.8 111.5 252.3 113.6 249.5 114.4 C 246.8 115.1 240.7 117.1 236 118.7 C 222.2 123.6 222.5 123.6 221.2 119.1 C 219.7 114.3 219.7 114 221.3 114 C 223.2 114 236.1 105 235.5 104.1 C 234.9 103.1 230.3 105.3 223.8 109.8 C 218.5 113.5 218 113.6 218 111.4 C 218 110.5 217 108.4 215.8 106.8 L 213.7 103.7 L 220.8 97.1 C 224.8 93.5 230.5 88.2 233.6 85.5 C 248.1 72.7 249.7 71 246.9 71 C 245.9 71 235.4 79.9 226.9 88 C 222.8 91.8 216.3 97.7 214.3 99.4 C 212.1 101.3 212 101.2 208.9 98.2 L 205.8 95.2 L 210.4 88.2 C 213 84.4 215.7 80.7 216.5 80 C 217.3 79.3 218 78.3 218 77.8 C 218 76.9 221.8 71.5 230.6 59.5 C 232.4 57.2 234.3 54.2 235 52.9 C 235.7 51.6 237.1 49.5 238.2 48.4 C 239.7 46.7 239.8 46 238.9 45.4 C 238.1 45 237.1 45.4 236.3 46.6 C 235.5 47.6 233.5 50.5 231.7 52.9 C 229.9 55.3 227.9 58.5 227.1 59.9 C 226.3 61.3 224.2 64.3 222.3 66.4 C 220.5 68.6 219 70.9 219 71.6 C 219 72.3 218.7 73 218.3 73.2 C 217.1 73.7 211 81.7 211 82.7 C 211 83.2 209.2 85.7 207.1 88.2 C 203.7 92.4 203.1 92.8 201.9 91.4 C 201.2 90.5 199.6 89.4 198.3 88.9 C 195.5 87.9 195.4 85.5 197.8 81.5 C 198.8 79.8 200.6 76 201.7 73 C 202.9 70 205.2 64.7 206.9 61.3 C 208.6 57.9 210 54.8 210 54.4 C 210 54 211.6 50.4 213.5 46.4 C 217.1 38.9 217.6 37 216.1 37 C 214.9 37 212.2 41.2 211.4 44.5 C 211 46 209 50.7 207 54.9 C 204.9 59.1 202.9 63.6 202.5 65 C 202.1 66.3 200.2 70.4 198.4 74 C 196.6 77.6 194.8 81.8 194.5 83.3 C 194.1 84.8 193.7 86 193.5 86 C 193.4 86 191.2 85.1 188.6 84 L 184 81.9 L 184.6 77.7 C 184.9 75.4 187.1 66.1 189.5 57 C 197 28 198.2 22.8 197.1 21.7 C 196.4 21 195.9 21.1 195.7 22.1 Z M 179 83.9 C 195.5 88.8 204.3 94.9 212.6 107.2 C 218.8 116.5 220.1 121.6 220.7 138.3 L 221.2 152 L 166.5 152 L 111.7 152 L 112.2 139.8 C 112.8 127.1 113.9 122.6 118.8 112 C 121.3 106.5 124.9 102 130.4 97.1 C 132 95.7 134.7 93.2 136.4 91.7 C 138.1 90.2 140.6 88.6 142 88.3 C 143.4 87.9 146.4 86.8 148.8 85.8 C 157.9 81.7 169.3 81 179 83.9 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_4"
                    android:pathData="M 50 36.3 C 50 37.5 58.2 45 59.4 45 C 61 45 59.5 42.4 55.9 38.9 C 51.7 34.8 50 34.1 50 36.3 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_5"
                    android:pathData="M 267 51.8 C 265.6 53.3 261.7 57 258.2 60 C 252 65.5 250.9 67 253.3 67 C 255.1 67 272.3 50.6 271.4 49.7 C 270.3 48.6 269.7 48.9 267 51.8 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_6"
                    android:pathData="M 74 87 C 74 87.5 74.4 88 74.9 88 C 75.4 88 77.1 89.1 78.7 90.4 C 84 94.9 97.9 102.9 98.6 101.9 C 98.9 101.3 99 100.7 98.9 100.6 C 98.7 100.4 95.8 98.5 92.6 96.4 C 77 86.1 74 84.6 74 87 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_7"
                    android:pathData="M 256.9 88.4 C 255 89.5 250.7 92.3 247.3 94.5 C 244 96.7 240.4 99 239.4 99.6 C 238 100.5 237.8 101.1 238.6 101.9 C 239.3 102.7 240.6 102.3 243.1 100.4 C 244.9 99 247.4 97.4 248.5 96.9 C 252.2 95.3 262.9 87.2 262.3 86.6 C 261.4 85.8 261 85.9 256.9 88.4 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_8"
                    android:pathData="M 3.5 124.9 C 2.7 126.3 6.1 127.6 13.3 128.4 C 17.9 128.9 19 128.7 19 127.6 C 19 126.6 17.4 125.9 14.3 125.5 C 11.6 125.2 8.3 124.6 6.8 124.4 C 5.4 124.1 3.9 124.4 3.5 124.9 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_9"
                    android:pathData="M 299.5 128.2 C 290.7 129.2 277.3 130.8 269.7 131.7 C 256.6 133.3 254.2 133.9 255.4 135.8 C 255.7 136.3 266.6 135.1 279.7 133.3 C 292.8 131.5 307.2 129.6 311.8 129.2 C 316.3 128.8 320.1 128 320.1 127.5 C 320.1 126 316.9 126.1 299.5 128.2 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_10"
                    android:pathData="M 23 127.7 C 23 128.2 35.3 130.3 50.3 132.4 C 84.2 137 81.5 136.8 81.5 135 C 81.5 133.5 71.7 131.9 43.5 129 C 37.5 128.4 30.4 127.6 27.8 127.3 C 25 127 23 127.1 23 127.7 Z"
                    android:fillColor="#cc0000"
                    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_3">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_4">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_5">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_6">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_7">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_8">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_9">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_10">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#cc0000"
                    android:valueTo="#3700b3"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="fillColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#3700b3"
                    android:valueTo="#ff9900"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```